# C# HTMLAgilityPack getting src. xpath is not valid

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am not able to get the xpath right. I am trying to get the image of any IMDB movie but it just seems not to work. This is my code of it.

```
 // Getting the node
            HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"title - overview - widget\"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/a/img");

            // Getting the attribute data
            HtmlAttributeCollection attr = node.Attributes;
```

the attribute is null. every time but. the xpath does not work and i dont know why. it seems good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simpler xpath

```
var url = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);

    var img = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@title='Trailer']")
              ?.Attributes["src"]?.Value;
    //or
    var poster = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='poster']//img")
                 ?.Attributes["src"]?.Value;
}
```